# Pyspark: No suitable Driver error while connecting to MS SQL Server 2017 from Spark 2.4 using Python

Tags: python, sql-server, jdbc, pyspark

I am facing a problem while running spark job using python i.e. pyspark. 
Please see below the code snippets

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from os.path import abspath
from pyspark.sql.functions import max,min,sum,col
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("test").config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "/usr/dt/mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar").getOrCreate()
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "Etc/UTC")
warehouse_loc = abspath('spark-warehouse')

#loading data from MS SQL Server 2017
df = spark.read.format("jdbc").options(url="jdbc:sqlserver://10.90.3.22;DATABASE=TransTrak_V_1.0;user=sa;password=m2m@ipcl1234",properties = { "driver": "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" },dbtable="Current_Voltage").load()
```

When I run this code, I am facing the following error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o38.load.
: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
```

**The same code used to run fine earlier**. However, due to some reasons, I had to reinstall centOS 7 again and then Python 3.6. I have set python 3.6 as a default python in spark i.e. when I start pyspark the default python is 3.6.

Just to mention, the system default python is Python 2.7. I am using centOS 7.

What is going wrong here? Can anybody please help on this?

Comment: Anybody please help. As I said, this was running fine earlier. Is it due to Spark 2.4.3 version?

Comment: I guess it is because that your jdbc driver doesn't match your db.

Comment: Have the same problem, Python3,openjdk in Mac

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so after long search, it appears that probably spark doesn't work properly with `openjdk` i.e. `java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.131-11.b12.el7.x86_64`. When I see the default Java I see it is as follows

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_131"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b12, mixed mode)
```

Then I tried to install Oracle JDK 8 from official site, however, then I faced separate issues. 
So in nutshell, I am not able to run the spark jobs like earlier.