# CentOS7: Setting default JAVA as Oracle JDK and not openJDK

Tags: java, centos

I have a machine with CentOS7. The default Java is

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_131"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b12, mixed mode)
```

I want to change this to

```
java version "1.8.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_51-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

To do so, I have so far followed the steps as given below.

1. Download jdk-8u212-linux-x64.tar.gz file
2. I could not untar the above using `tar -zxvf jdk-8u212-linux64.tar.gz`to a specified directory. Hence I used 7-zip and the extracted the JDK1.8.0_212 folder and copied the same to `/usr/lib/jvm`
3. Then I made the necessary changes at `/etc/profile`. There I set the JAVA_HOME as `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_212` and followed by `export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME\bin`

However, when I typed `update-alternatives --config java` I could not see `jdk1.8.0_212/bin/java` as path. Instead I saw only `openjdk` options.

My question is: How to set my default Java as Oracle Java as mentioned above. The reason I am asking is I have found that `sqljdbc4-x.jar` is not compatible with openJDK. I have already raised a query [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56953115/pyspark-no-suitable-driver-error-while-connecting-to-ms-sql-server-2017-from-sp)

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach would be to first remove Open JDK using purge then install Oracle jdk..if u are using apt-get it would automatically set the necessary Java Paths.

Here is what I meant.

```
yum list java*
sudo yum -y remove java*
java -version
cd
mkdir tmp
cd tmp
curl -u uftp:uftp ftp://192.168.2.115/path/developer/jdk-8u151-linux-x64.tar.gz -o jdk-8u151-linux-x64.tar.gz
tar zxvf jdk-8u151-linux-x64.tar.gz
sudo mv jdk1.8.0_151 /usr/share/
sudo vim /etc/profile
#add
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/share/jdk1.8.0_151
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/lib/dt.jar:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar
source /etc/profile
java -version
which java
```

cheers.

Comment: Hi morrisng, can you please elaborate?

Comment: Thanks. I tried in a similar line. However, I ended up getting `segmentation fault (core dumped)` . I am seeing this error message when I type `java -version` i

Comment: what exactly did u try?

Comment: 1. Remove Java using `yum -y remove java` 2. Download jdk-8u51-linux.x_64.rpm and then install using `yum install`. 3. Set the JAVA_HOME at `/etc/profile`, PATH and JRE_HOME.